# App crashes when trying to load from SQLite

Tags: ios, sqlite

Well, I am making an update to an app I made, but I am having some runtime issues. People said they wanted to be able to save data they entered, so I am implementing an SQLite database. I got the app to check if database exists and create everything needed, if the database or database table does not exist. However, I am having troubles retrieving data from SQLite. When I press a button that should load data, the app crashes. I tried using both NSLog and UIAlertView to figure out what is going on, but I cannot retrieve results. However, when performing a test run in SQLite, the query I am issuing is correct, so there must be something else.

the following is the code I am using to retrieve data:

```
- (IBAction)loadData
{
    NSDateFormatter* bf = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [bf setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSDate* sdate;
    NSString* birthDate;
    NSString* balance;
    NSString* dyear;

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    // get document directory
    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // build path to database
    dbpath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mrd.db"]];

    const char *dpath = [dbpath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dpath, &mrdDB) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        NSString* query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT date(birth), bal, year FROM rmd LIMIT 1"];
        const char* query_statement = [query UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(mrdDB, query_statement, -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
                birthDate = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)];
                balance = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2)];
                dyear = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 3)];

                sdate = [bf dateFromString:birthDate];

                self.birth.text = [bf stringFromDate:sdate];
                [birthDate release];
                [bf release];

                self.bal.text = balance;
                [balance release];

                self.year.text = dyear;
                [dyear release];

                self.status.text = @"data loaded sucessfully";

            } else {
                self.status.text = @"Cannot find/retrieve saved data";
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
       }
       sqlite3_close(mrdDB);
    }
 }
```

The app is able to save data to the database, as the app displays a "save successful" message, which I added for the user's sake as well as seeing if things were done right, so I am not too sure what is going on.

Comment: The error reported is pointing at "int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);" and the error is "Program received signal: 'SIGABRT'" (single quote are used in placed of double quotes here).

Comment: Look at your stack to find the offending line of code. Or just as easily, set a debugging breakpoint in this routine and step through it and see where you have your problem. I wonder about your retrieving the date as a string, converting it to a date, and converting it back to a string. I wouldn't be surprised if sdate, for example, was nil (because does it conform to your dateformatter format string). I don't know. But single step through this routine and your problem will leap out at you.

Comment: BTW, did you say you see the "save successful" message (or I guess the "data loaded sucessfully" [sic] message)? That's weird. It will be very interesting what your single-stepping through the code tells you...

Comment: @RobertRyan Yes, the look through on the database and how data was saved did indeed have either nothing, zero, or null. I found and fixed the date formatting after a while. The message my app sent was "save successful", but due to the fact that the database in the simulator was not agreeing with input, I ran tests until it produced things right.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem, after finding where the simulator saves databases. My problem was not with the loading the data, but how it was saved. Thanks for the help.